# Ionic 2 ion-segment, how to get the segment html?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ng-switch

I have this simple `ion-segment`

html

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="type" (ionChange)="selectedTabChanged($event)">
    <ion-segment-button value="a">a</ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="b">b</ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>


 <div [ngSwitch]="type">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'a'">

        <ion-select #typeSelect (ionChange)="setMake($event)">
            <ion-option value="x">x</ion-option>
        </ion-select> 

    </div>

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'b'">b</div>
</div>
```

js

```
export class MyPage {
    @ViewChild('typeSelect') typeSelect;

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.type = 'a';
    }

    selectedTabChanged($event): void {
        console.log(this.typeSelect);
    }
}
```

Expectation:

- when I tap on `a` i expect to get `this.typeSelect`
- when I tap on `b` i expect to get `this.typeSelect` as undefined, because `ion-select` is only in the `a` view

But I get the value backwards. I think that when I tap on `b` it looks for the html from `a` and vice-versa.

Any ideas?

edit:

looks like if I wrap the change in a timeout it works fine. But the problem is that I don't know how link it takes for the DOM elements to get `un-hidden` by the `ngSwitch`

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.typeSelect);
}, 1000);
```